# When I run/debug C program, malloc() seems to be assigning "r\r\r\r\r\r..." to a pointer and I am not sure why?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, cs50

I am working through the Harvard cs50x courses and I have purposefully been avoiding using their cs50.h library so that I don't have another hoop to jump through re-learning how to code certain things in C.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void){
    // Prompt to enter text & allocate memory for string of 100 char
    char *text = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter Text: ");
    fgets(text, 100, stdin);

    // Calculate index
    int number_of_words = countWords(text);
    int number_of_letters = countLetters(text);
    int number_of_sentences = countSentences(text);

    float L = (float) number_of_letters / number_of_words * 100.0;
    float S = (float) number_of_sentences / number_of_words * 100.0;

    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

    // Print index from if > 1 "less than 1" and if greater that 16 "16+" else print index
    if (index < 1){
        printf("Reading Level: Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (index > 16){
        printf("Reading Level: Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Reading Level: Grade %i\n", index);
    }
    // Free memory and terminate program
    free(text);
    return 0;
}


// Count functions use a while loop to iterate through each char and count then return total count as int
// Removed due to Stack Overflow saying i have too much code in post
```

It's purpose is to get input from the user as a string, then parse that information to provide a reading level.

**The Issue: **
I am able to run and debug this code on cs50.dev, and it appears to work exactly as I intended. The very first line of main() sets the text variable, per my image below:

[text: 0x55ed3e7412a0 "" / *text: 0 '\000'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJAEU.png)

However, trying to run/debug on my local Windows machine results in the text variable being set per below:

[text: 0x7416e0 "\r\r\r\r\r..." / *text: 13 '\r'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf2cn.png)

I don't understand why this is happening, and I am not sure where to even start looking. Obviously it has something to do with the malloc() function, but i dont understand what it could be allocating that is different from what it allocates on cs50.dev.

I imagine this is an issue with my setup of VScode, or possibly my setup of MinGW? Any assistance here is greatly appreciated. Any additional comments on how to improve my code as well would be appreciated.

Comment: "Obviously it has something to do with the malloc() function" is a dubious conclusion. Why would that be a factor? Check *before* you call `fgets`. Additionally, and this is important, **always** check the return value of **functions that can fail**. Maybe `fgets` is saying "No can do" but you're not listening.

Comment: Although your suspicions about `malloc()` are likely unfounded, you could have tested this versus a buffer like `char text[100]` and see if you get similar results.

Comment: Another great way to understand the behavior of a standard function is to read its documentation. On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), the very first paragraph states: _"Allocates size bytes of **uninitialized** storage."_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: Site-note: `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1.

Comment: Interesting, thank you both. I think the main reason i figured it was the malloc() function is because thats where things initially broke down on the windows machine, and in cs50 dev it went fone and the rest of the code performed exactly how I wanted when i stepped over each line in the debugger. I will give the buffer you noted a go and see what changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "broke down"? That code does not rely on the content of the buffer. Seeing unexpected variable content in the debugger does not affect running the code if that variable content is not used at all.

Comment: The story behind it all is that malloc purposely does not initialize the memory, making it faster, in case you intend to overwrite that memory anyway (which is often the case). For the rarer case where you need a zero-initialized buffer, there is calloc. C is like a sports car, fast but dangerous if you are careless. Whereas a higher level language would perhaps always zero-initialize the memory because it prioritizes ruggedness over speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrongly assume that the memory allocated by `malloc` is zeroed. In fact, its content is not determined and you have entered the unchartered area of ***Undefined Behaviour***
. It is why you are getting different content of the allocated block when compiled and run using different compilers.

If you want to have it zeroed:

```
 char *text = calloc(100,1);
```

Comment: Reading uninitialized dynamically allocated memory results in indeterminate values, not undefined behavior.

Comment: An alternative is to just use an array. 100 bytes on the stack is not gonna break the bank in most scenarios, possibly with the exception of extremely tiny embedded environments. It still needs to be initialized at some point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil he is printing it as a C string which is an UB.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the calloc() method as well and ill make aure to take a look at the documentation so i know what's going on there.

Comment: Watching the content in debugger is not the same as printing. The code fills the buffer using `fgets` immediately after allocating it. No UB here.

Comment: Thank you to gulpr, this solution fixed the issue I was having quickly and easily.

Comment: It has less (or nothing) to do with different compilers and more to do with different execution environments, how/if the OS initialises memory provided to the heap, and whether the heap is providing a previously used block or a pristine block.  No action, simply means you get whatever happens to be in memory, and the compiler dies not define that.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `calloc`, you can use  `memset` from `<string.h>` to zero out the array after calling `malloc`:

```c
    memset(text, 0, 100);
```